# add a cgroup controller into libvirt

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, network-monitoring, libvirt, cgroup

libvirt by default has cgroup controllers of ["cpu", "devices", "memory", "blkio", "cpuacct"] as shown in qemu.conf. I want to add one more controller of net_cls. I tried to modify the config file to make the update.

```
cgroup_controllers = ["cpu", "devices", "memory", "blkio", "cpuacct", "net_cls"]
```

I restarted cgroup and libvirt service but the new controller didn't show up. How to add net_cls to libvirt group in cgroup?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like libvirt supports the net_cls controller:

"The net_cls is not currently used. Instead traffic filter policies are set directly against individual virtual network interfaces"

Directly copied from http://libvirt.org/cgroups.html